# Can we get embedded YouTube videos?

Tags: feature-request, editor

[Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) and [Scifi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) both allow embedding YouTube videos by posting the URL on its own line. I think there is use here for this as well, as long as the moderators and high rep users police the content and make sure it's relevant (which is no different from embedded images). Given that anime is a video medium, it seems rather relevant for us.

I recently asked a question, [Is there any explanation for "Tequila" in the Kuragehime eyecatch?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/2586/24), which I linked to a 6-second YouTube video. It would be much better if the video were embedded so that people wouldn't have to open a new page just to watch the video.

There was support for this on the [Area51 page](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8468/could-embeded-youtube-video-be-allowed), but it never happened. Can we get this turned on?

Comment: This could be abused horribly. If this were to happen, we need to make clear guidelines where embedding a video is OK.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha It seems to work fine on the other sites which have it. I don't think the guidelines need to be any different from our guidelines for embedding images. If people are embedding entire episodes to answer questions, that isn't okay, in the same way that embedding entire manga chapters isn't okay even if the answer is contained therein.

Comment: Is there a reputation restriction?

Comment: @Eric I could not find any discussion of required reputation to embed videos. I'd assume it's at least the same as images (registered with at least 10 rep) but I could be mistaken.

Comment: This may also cause issues with copyrighted material, right?

Comment: @Singer we agreed that we "don't care" about copyright problems unless someone complains. Also, it's YouTube's problem, not ours.

Comment: @Madara, `we agreed that we "don't care" about copyright problems unless` - I probably missed that. Could you please share a link?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/a/406/122 :)

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall: also: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/conversation/copyright-material-in-posts-4-chat-cast

Comment: Even keeping aside the `we don't care about copyright` part, I don't think its a copyright problem, because youtube videos get embedded all over the internet. I don't know how the embedding works on those other SE sites, but as long as the embedded video links back to the Youtube page, it shouldn't cause any problem.

Comment: @LoganM There is one significant difference in policing. You don't need to do anything special to see the embedded image, but to decide if a video is appropriate, you would have to buffer it, etc. and watch it for maybe 3 to 5 minutes. However, I do think this would be useful. So I would suggest that the video shouldn't be longer than (say) 60 seconds.

Comment: ^ That's just a guideline. If a longer video is required to make the Q or A clear, then the poster has to state so clearly with the reason. Also, if only a specific portion of the video is relevant, state that too (Example: See 1:35 to 2:30, in this video). With that, the above 60 second rule could refer to only the "effective" video length.

Comment: @looper, thanks ;)

Comment: @Deidara-senpai I think any use of video in general needs some explanation. Not just "This video answers your question," but more to the effect of "Here's the clip from episode 638 where the narrator says that Ash is 10 years old." There may be cases where a longer video is needed, but as long as there's an explanation for what the video is supposed to show, it's easy to decide whether or not it's relevant within a few seconds in most cases. I think we'll always have enough active users that someone will notice if a video isn't relevant and flag it.

Comment: @Deidara-senpai The only exception I can find to that is if someone embeds something in Japanese without subtitles and with no translation provided. I think we'd frown on that in the same way that we'd frown on an answer in Japanese without any translation.

Comment: @LoganM Yes I agree that video-only answers should be treated the same way as link-only answers. But if I want to refer to a 60-second segment in a 10 minute video, I would have to tell you what I am referring to. This is especially true for questions.

Comment: @LoganM Also I too would like to have the embedded video feature. This [comment](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2578/why-does-chopper-hide-himself-the-wrong-way#comment1778_2579) is one such example. Of course, it is a comment and a side-discussion (not related directly to the question) so a video is not strictly required, but it illustrates why an embedded video could be useful.

Comment: @Deidara-senpai Naturally for longer videos, the poster should refer to the proper start time of the clip, and ideally also embed the video so that it starts at that time. I'd always prefer if the video was as trimmed as possible though. As you probably already know, even if this gets added we won't have videos in comments, just questions and answers, but there are definitely cases where videos could be useful.