# Can we have embedded YouTube videos enabled?

Tags: feature-request

During beta, it was suggested that embedded YouTube videos be turned on in this [meta post](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/434/17758). I think that as a recreation site, it would be nice to have these links auto-embed similar to the way they do on Arqade and other stack exchange recreation sites.

It seems this feature-request was ignored the first time around because the site was still in beta, so I'd like to see if we can get some traction on getting this turned on now that the site has graduated.

Example questions where YouTube embedding could have been beneficial:

[How can I improve the frame rate of a low frame rate anime?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/30128/17758)
[Where does the word "Nyanpasu" come from?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/13637/17758)
[Meaning of telegraph code in the song planetes](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/18403/17758)
[What is this buzzing sound playing?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/7824/17758)
[What did Guy say in his fight vs Madara?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/26181/17758)
[Why do rich people laugh like they do in anime?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/14405/17758)
[What's the name of this song from Episode 16 of Shingeki no Kyojin?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/26322/17758)
[Which song is this from Prince of Tennis?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/11672/17758)
[What episode do Gintoki and Hijikata fight in a roof?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/15315/17758)

Comment: I think movies and tv have this now too

Comment: I don't think that this was ignored because we were in beta. It was ignored because no one could actually find any examples of answers which would be significantly improved  by allowing embedded videos. If you can find a few such examples that would go a long way to proving this would actually be useful here.

Comment: An example that comes to mind is a question I want to post about how to increase frame-rate for low frame anime. There's an example video of this in action that would fit nicely into my answer.

Comment: I'll search for more examples throughout the site a bit later tonight. If anyone finds any they'd like to mention, feel free to edit the original post.

Comment: Science Fiction and Fantasy also has this. From what I've seen, most of the answers that use embedded video don't actually *need* it; they could usually get by just as well with screenshots. But it can be a nice feature, as long as people still take the time to explain their answers and don't just plunk some video in and call it a day.

Comment: We got it over [movies and TV in 2014](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/631/video-embedding-for-movies-se) (before graduation) but its better if you can show few example where its required, as we did and it worked.

Comment: Anyways i never realized its not present here.

Comment: Due to the nature of our site, whatever we cite from youtube, it's most likely that they will be promptly removed in the future, except for AMV or very short excerpt from the anime. I don't think we really need them. As for existing posts, you can just embed an image from the anime instead.

Comment: No stack exchange site really "needs" videos. I don't think the argument of not needing them is a very good argument against having videos embed and not having to leave site to watch a video. Videos on YouTube *might* get removed, but that risk is already there with having a YouTube link included in an answer, embedding it doesn't increase that chance.

Comment: Enabling YouTube would allow asker to just put the video up and ask question about it **without pointing to the exact episode/timestamp**, especially the case for the last half of your list. This makes such question not searchable, and editing them would require quite some effort.

Comment: That can happen just like it does now, and you would resolve it the exact same way: close as too little detail to be answered (minimum guidelines not met). YouTube is pretty well censored already, I think we should enable embedding.